# Can I use inheritance in remote/local interfaces? (EJB3)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

An example:

```
@Remote
public interface SomeComponentRemote{

    public Something processStuff();

}

//--

@Local
public interface SomeComponentLocal extends SomeComponentRemote{

}
```

Is that allowed? Can i do this regularly?

Answer (score 5):

Your way is not allowed as you can not mark your interface with both @Local and @Remote annotations according to specification. And it is not a good idea from point of code reading.

Recommended solution is

```
public interface SomeComponent {
    public Something processStuff();
}

@Local
public interface SomeComponentLocal extends SomeComponent {
}

@Remote
public interface SomeComponentRemote extends SomeComponent {
}
```

Comment: The idea is write less code. In this way I´ll have one more interface for each bean.

Thanks anyway man.

Comment: The main idea is to write maintainable and expressive code and not tricky one. To make future guys happier do not trick.

Comment: +1 The main idea is to write code that doesn't violate the spec :-) Using @Local and @Remote on the same interface will compile, but won't deploy properly.

Comment: Just because it's possible to expose an interface as both local and remote doesn't always make it a good idea:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184354/ejb3-session-bean-calling-method-of-another-bean-interface/1192049#1192049

Comment: Hm, are you really sure this violates the spec? I don't think so: Annotations are not inherited - so you have one local and one remote interface. This is perfectly valid in my eyes.

Comment: Annotations CAN be inherited, but only if they're designed as such (with @Inherited). Local and Remote are not, so they're not inherited and the questioner's technique is therefore perfectly valid. I personally would prefer to have the Remote be an extension of Local (its a specialisation), but that's a minor quibble.

Answer (score 3):

This code will work since @local/@remote annotations are not inherited. Is is also possible to set a no-interface-view on the bean itself with @LocalBean while implementing the remote interface (instead of a local interface).

The more important point is that every interface should only offer what is needed for the users of this class because every method you offer will be probably used and then you have to maintain this method.

The question is what you are going to do: will both interfaces offer the same methods all the time? Or is one interface a possible subset of the other (if you extend local from remote then it suggests that perhaps not every addition to local will be offered as remote).
The same for @LocalBean - are there public methods that are just accessed by the ejb-container and not conceived for other users?

The only bad thing you can do is designing an interface by laziness rather than intention. Neither excludes to write less code.